# Configure default schema for Doctrine 2.5 and PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, database-schema

I'm building a **PHP** application and I'm using Doctrine 2.5 to map my objects into the database. My database choice is PostgreSQL 10.

Instead of using the default schema (`public`), I've tagged *all* my classes with `@ORM\Table(schema="my-schema")` so it uses this schema instead of the default one. This works as intended: all the tables are created on that schema.

But I've found that tables for `ManyToMany` relations are not being created in my schema; instead they're created on the default one 
(I suppose this is occurring because they're not backed up with a class on my model).

Then my question is if it's possible to configure somewhere the default schema I want Doctrine to use (this would also allow me to get rid of all the `@ORM\Table(schema="my-schema")` annotations). Maybe that is a bug on Doctrine, I don't know. Any kind of workaround to prevent this also would be appreciated.

Comment: You could change your Postgres user so that it defaults to your schema: `alter user your_user set search_path = my_schema`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, it works perfectly.